# Xamarin Form IsVisible property with animation

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a `xamarin` stack layout when user scroll the list view search section should be hide like WhatsApp search area.but now I`m using`IsVisibl`e property to hide the area.when`IsVisible` false that section imitatively hide out what i need is it should be hide out with an animation (Like WhatsApp)

I have tried this [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/24263/is-there-a-way-to-do-a-fadeto-when-an-isvisible-binding-is-switched) !
But it seems IsVisible is firing first i guess not the fade effect

```cs
<StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding Isvisible}" 
PropertyChanged="Isvisible_OnPropertyChanged" 
 </StackLayout>
```

```
private void SearchArea_OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           if (e.PropertyName != "IsVisible") return;
           var viewModel = (StackLayout)sender;
           if (!viewModel.IsVisible)
           {
               searchArea.FadeTo(0, 5000, Easing.SpringOut);
           }

       }
```

What need to be happen is smoothly my StackLayout should be hide out with animation effect like fade out.
This should be applied to both android and IOS

Answer (score 2):

The FadeTo method change the Opacity value with effect

```
// Fade out over 3 seconds
myStackName.FadeTo(0, 3000);
// Fade in over 1 second
myStackName.FadeTo(1, 1000);
```

Set opacity to 0 and after set 0 height to search area...

Comment: ```csharp
private void Isvisible_OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName != "IsVisible") return;
            var viewModel = (StackLayout)sender;
            if (!viewModel.IsVisible)
            {
                searchArea.FadeTo(0, 5000, Easing.SpringOut);
            }

        }
 ```  
I have use this Property on change value but issue still the same "searchArea" is by stacklayout name

Comment: You can use the property HeightRequest and set the value from 0 to its truth height with animation .